# Wicket session Expiration

Tags: java, wicket

i am using a class for session which extends org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession;
i need a method to be called when this session expires as a consequence of logging out or time out. but i have found nothing. How can i do it?

Comment: Help us help you by telling us _what_ it is you have to do when a session expires.. This might help in finding a solution to your problem. As a side note: Could you handle "whatever it is you need to do" by catching a PageExpiredException (that may or may not come)?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it on Wicket level like this:

by overriding SessionStore implementation - override Application#newSessionStore()

```
 @Override
 protected ISessionStore newSessionStore() {
        return new SecondLevelCacheSessionStore(this, new DiskPageStore()) {

            @Override
            protected void onUnbind(String sessionId) {
                // this code is called when wicket call httpSession.invalidate()
            }

        };
    }
```

but this has drawback: when session expires (which is constroled by servlet container) this code won't be called. In other words - you can handle only session destroy event which is caused by wicket itself.

On global level you can use Servlet API's [HttpSessionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) - you can react on session destroy event whatever it was triggered by

```
HttpSesionListener#sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)
```

and write this to your WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>
     your.listener.class.full.qualified.name
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 2):

Session.java has a callback method that is executed when the user session is invalidated or due to HttpSession expiration.

```
public void onInvalidate(){
}
```

Comment: This answer is superior to the other one from 2009 as it caters for both scenarios in which a session can become invalidated. From the Wicket 6.x doco:

"A callback method that is executed when the user session is invalidated either by explicit call to invalidate() or due to HttpSession expiration."